# How can I add only Skype to the Indicator applet in Ubuntu Mate?

Tags: indicator, skype, mate, applet

If I add the Indicator Applet to my panel

[image: Add to Panel screen]

I get Skype and some other notification icons

[image: Indicator Applet]

but is there way to only get Skype? Is there a different applet I should be using? Pidgin doesn't seem to have this problem and shows up in the Notification Area applet.

Comment: Sorry, I am running 19.10

Comment: If I got you correctly - then you can try "Notification Area" applet instead of "Indicator Applet".

Comment: The problem is Skype icon will not show up there, it only appears in the Indicator Applet. I have them both running at the moment.